# ldap_search_ext_s filter compiler warning

Tags: c++, ldap-query

Does [`ldap_search_ext_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/aa366972(v=vs.85).aspx) accepts null filters? I've used it in this way for years but the Visual Studio Code Analyzer is complaining about that. What is the proper way to query with no filters without this warning?

Comment: What way you have used ldap_search_ext_s for years? What is "The Code Analyzer"? What it is complaining? Proper way to query what? What warning?

Comment: @ÖöTiib using null meaning "no filter"...? complaining about using null as filter...? proper way to query using no filters...? Warning of the analyzer about using null as filter...?

Comment: I think in Linux filter may be NULL to mean all objects but in Windows you must use filter "(objectClass=*)" to mean all objects, but I may be wrong.